# Let's Encrypt SSL on Google Cloud

Tags: apache-2.4, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, lets-encrypt, debian-stretch

I am utterly failing to find a working guide for installing Let's Encrypt certificates on a single Google Cloud virtual machine.

I'm pretty clearly getting the picture that just doing the Apache webserver configuration isn't enough.

The information here, https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates , seems to assume I'm doing load balancing--um, I'm on a tight budget here so it's only the one virtual machine. No load balancing.

I found some gcloud commands somewhere which I translate as:

- gcloud compute ssl-certificates create partsunknownorg
  --certificate=/etc/letsencrypt/live/parts-unknown.org/fullchain.pem --private-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/parts-unknown.org/privkey.pem
- gcloud compute target-https-proxies update partsunknownorg
  --certificate=/etc/letsencrypt/live/parts-unknown.org/fullchain.pem --private-key=/etc/letsencrypt/live/parts-unknown.org/privkey.pem

I used the first one to try to install the certificates; I gather I should use the second to update them. Is that right?

In any event, it seems not to have worked. And I'm baffled.

Comment: If you have only a single virtual machine, why are you bothering with instructions for a load balancer (which presumably you don't have)? Or anything unusual at all? Just install Let's Encrypt normally. Being on Google Cloud isn't even relevant in your scenario.

Comment: If you're not using Google's load balancers, don't use any of the `gcloud` commands. Just follow a Let's Encrypt tutorial for your Linux distribution. *edit:* Argh, too slow! :-p

Comment: Being on Google Cloud seems to be extremely relevant. I'm flat out getting SSL protocol errors with a configuration that worked when I wasn't on Google Cloud. As near as I can tell, I need to facilitate a man-in-the-middle here, the "man" being Google Cloud, but I can't tell how to feed it the keys.

I tried looking at Google's SSL service, but that doesn't make any sense either.

Comment: For what it's worth, I also had to feed it ssh keys--editing ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file like I've done since time immemorial leads to a situation where ssh simply stops working.

Comment: There shouldn't be any man in the middle. Your domain should be pointed directly at the instance's IP if you're not using load balancing. The SSL error is probably a misconfiguration on your part. Follow a LE tutorial for your distribution, then test it out using something like https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and see what issues they report.

Comment: There absolutely is a man-in-the-middle. Google doesn't provide these instances with direct access to routable IP addresses. One attaches an external (routable) address through their web configuration and this man-in-the-middle forwards the traffic. That's the way they do it, which I assume offers a layer of security, but complicates end-to-end cryptography.

Comment: You assume incorrectly, to my knowledge. Calling Google's external IP implementation a "man in the middle" isn't accurate.